Rserve chrome can not view table
When I open RStudio Server (2023.12.0 Build 369) in Chrome (Version 129.0.6668.59 (Official Build) (64-bit)), I can not view the table in R environment.
enter image description here
I perfer to use Chrome because of its stability, so I want to fix the table view problems. I would be grateful if you can give me some suggestions.
But when I open RStudio Server in Microsoft Edge (128.0.2739.79), it works well.
enter image description here
